# Regex - Find from both sides only if it has spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help on Regex. I need to find a word that is surrounded by whatever element, for example - `*`. But I need to match it only if it has spaces or nothing on the ether sides. For example if it is at start of the text I can't really have space there, same for end.

Here is what I came up to

```
    string myString = "You will find *me*, and *me* also!";
    string findString = @"(\*(.*?)\*)";
    string foundText;
    MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(myString, findString);
    foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
    {
        foundText = match.Value.Replace("*", "");
        myString = myString.Replace(match.Value, "->" + foundText + "<-");
        match.NextMatch();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

`You will find ->me<-, and ->me<- also!`

Works correct, the problem is when I add `*` in the middle of text, I don't want it to match then.

Example: `You will find *m*e*, and *me* also!`
Output: `You will find ->m<-e->, and <-me* also!`

How can I fix that?

Comment: You wrote 'if it has spaces or nothing on the ether sides'. But this part `*me*,` doesn't has spaces or nothing. It has coma. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
string findString = @"(?<=\s|^)\*(.*?)\*(?=\s|$)";
```

- `(?<=\s|^)X` will match any `X` only if preceded by a space-char (`\s`), or the start-of-input, and
- `X(?=\s|$)` matches any `X` if followed by a space-char (`\s`), or the end-of-input.

Note that it will not match `*me*` in `foo *me*, bar` since the second `*` has a `,` after it! If you want to match that too, you need to include the comma like this:

```
string findString = @"(?<=[\s,]|^)\*(.*?)\*(?=[\s,]|$)";
```

You'll need to expand the set `[\s,]` as you see fit, of course. You might want to add `!`, `?` and `.` at the very least: `[\s,!?.]` (and no, `.` and `?` do *not* need to be escaped inside a character-set!).

### EDIT

A small demo:

```
string Txt = "foo *m*e*, bar";
string Pattern = @"(?<=[\s,]|^)\*(.*?)\*(?=[\s,]|$)";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Txt, Pattern, ">$1<"));
```

which would print:

```
>m*e<
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, and Ruslan had a valid point, thanks for fixing that also. Maybe you could just help with one more thing if it's not too hard to do. How can I escape characters? For example *m\*e* would show as ->m*e<-?

Comment: This is actually a bit buggy on the original string. It will match `"*me*, and *me*"` as its capture.

Comment: I think inverting the logic and using `@"(?<!\w)\*(.*?)\*(?!\w)"` is a better fit. That means the expression is not followed or preceded by a 'word character'. This way you don't have to add lots of characters to exclude them :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add "beginning of line or space" and "space or end of line" around your match:

```
(^|\s)\*(.*?)\*(\s|$)
```

You'll now need to refer to the middle capture group for the match string.